# How to prove that $a+b$ and $a-b$ are coprime when $a$ and $b$ are coprime and their parities are different?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

When *a* and *b* are coprime and their parities are different,

How to prove that $a+b$ and $a-b$ are coprime?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score -2):

let $d\in\{\text{primes}\}\cup\{1\}$ s.t. $d|a+b,a-b\implies d|(a+b)+(a-b)=2a$ and $d|(a+b)-(a-b)=2b$, additionally $d\not= 2 $ (because $a+b$ is odd by hypothesis) $\implies d|a,b \implies d=1$

Comment: Unnecessary to assume $d$ prime.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).